# Is there a library function for Root mean square error (RMSE) in python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy

I know I could implement a root mean squared error function like this:

```
def rmse(predictions, targets):
    return np.sqrt(((predictions - targets) ** 2).mean())
```

What I'm looking for if this rmse function is implemented in a library somewhere, perhaps in scipy or scikit-learn?

Comment: you wrote the function right there. Most likely if the function is that simple to write, it is not going to be in a library. you're better off creating a director called modules and just putting useful functions in it and adding it to your path

Comment: @RyanSaxe I disagree. I would find it a lot more reassuring to call a library function than to reimplement it myself. For instance, I wrote `.sum()` instead of `.mean()` first by mistake. In addition, I suppose this function is used so much that I see no reason why it shouldn't be available as a library function.

Comment: @siamii: I understand that 100%, I was just speculating at the reason why this kind of function may not be in scipy. If it is I cannot seem to find it

Comment: Actually, I did write a bunch of those as utility functions for statsmodels http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/tools.html#measure-for-fit-performance-eval-measures and http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.tools.eval_measures.rmse.html#statsmodels.tools.eval_measures.rmse Mostly one or two liners and not much input checking, and mainly intended for easily getting some statistics when comparing arrays. But they have unit tests for the axis arguments, because that's where I sometimes make sloppy mistakes.

Comment: To people who tried this and it didn't work: if `predictions` and `targets` are for example of type `int16` the square might overflow (giving negative numbers). So you might need an `.astype('int')` or `.astype('double')` before using the square, like `np.sqrt(((predictions - targets).astype('double') ** 2).mean())`.

Comment: Another advantage of having this in sklearn is the sklearn implementations have a lot of additional boiler plate code to ensure the arrays are of the same shape, and includes the weights parameters and also handles multi-dimensional arrays and different 'array likes'. Doing all that turns this into a much more complex problem

Comment: There is new feature in sklean where you can get rmse directly.   https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error.html

Answer (score 378):

**sklearn >= 0.22.0**

`sklearn.metrics` has a `mean_squared_error` function with a `squared` kwarg (defaults to `True`). Setting `squared` to `False` will return the RMSE.

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

rms = mean_squared_error(y_actual, y_predicted, squared=False)
```

**sklearn < 0.22.0**

`sklearn.metrics` has a `mean_squared_error` function. The RMSE is just the square root of whatever it returns.

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from math import sqrt

rms = sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_actual, y_predicted))
```

Comment: `squared` false to return RMSE seems like a misleading name since aren't we still doing squaring but just putting a root over it? IMO, more accurate parameter name should have been `root` boolean so that you let function know if you want to take the root or not. What am I missing.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since it rightly tells how we can do RMSE. I also agree with @THISUSERNEEDSHELP regarding the argument name, it is misleading. It should have been some other argument name.

Comment: @THISUSERNEEDSHELP its not that. The difference between RMSE and MSE is only that we calculate the Root of MSE in RMSE, which means we can call MSE the square of RMSE, and that exactly is what this parameter is doing.

Comment: @DaniyalAhmadSE Thanks. That makes a ton of sense. I understand the reasoning, but it is still confusing to not include the intuitive "root" into the argument

Answer (score 173):

### What is RMSE?  Also known as MSE, RMD, or RMS.  What problem does it solve?

If you understand RMSE: (Root mean squared error), MSE: (Mean Squared Error) RMD (Root mean squared deviation) and RMS: (Root Mean Squared), then asking for a library to calculate this for you is unnecessary over-engineering.  All these can be intuitively written in a single line of code.  rmse, mse, rmd, and rms are different names for the same thing.

RMSE answers: "How similar, on average, are the numbers in `list1` to `list2`?".  The two lists must be the same size.  Wash out the noise between any two given elements, wash out the size of the data collected, and get a single number result".

### Intuition and ELI5 for RMSE.  What problem does it solve?:

Imagine you are learning to throw darts at a dart board.  Every day you practice for one hour.  You want to figure out if you are getting better or getting worse.  So every day you make 10 throws and measure the distance between the bullseye and where your dart hit.

You make a list of those numbers `list1`.  Use the root mean squared error between the distances at day 1 and a `list2` containing all zeros.  Do the same on the 2nd and nth days.  What you will get is a single number that hopefully decreases over time.  When your RMSE number is zero, you hit bullseyes every time.  If the rmse number goes up, you are getting worse.

### **Example in calculating root mean squared error in python:**

```
import numpy as np
d = [0.000, 0.166, 0.333]   #ideal target distances, these can be all zeros.
p = [0.000, 0.254, 0.998]   #your performance goes here

print("d is: " + str(["%.8f" % elem for elem in d]))
print("p is: " + str(["%.8f" % elem for elem in p]))

def rmse(predictions, targets):
    return np.sqrt(((predictions - targets) ** 2).mean())

rmse_val = rmse(np.array(d), np.array(p))
print("rms error is: " + str(rmse_val))
```

Which prints:

```
d is: ['0.00000000', '0.16600000', '0.33300000']
p is: ['0.00000000', '0.25400000', '0.99800000']
rms error between lists d and p is: 0.387284994115
```

### **The mathematical notation:**

[image: root mean squared deviation explained]

**Glyph Legend:** `n` is a whole positive integer representing the number of throws.  `i` represents a whole positive integer counter that enumerates sum.  `d` stands for the ideal distances, the `list2` containing all zeros in above example.  `p` stands for performance, the `list1` in the above example.  superscript 2 stands for numeric squared.  **d<sub>i</sub>** is the i'th index of `d`.  **p<sub>i</sub>** is the i'th index of `p`.

**The rmse done in small steps so it can be understood:**

```
def rmse(predictions, targets):

    differences = predictions - targets                       #the DIFFERENCEs.

    differences_squared = differences ** 2                    #the SQUAREs of ^

    mean_of_differences_squared = differences_squared.mean()  #the MEAN of ^

    rmse_val = np.sqrt(mean_of_differences_squared)           #ROOT of ^

    return rmse_val                                           #get the ^
```

### How does every step of RMSE work:

Subtracting one number from another gives you the distance between them.

```
8 - 5 = 3         #absolute distance between 8 and 5 is +3
-20 - 10 = -30    #absolute distance between -20 and 10 is +30
```

If you multiply any number times itself, the result is always positive because negative times negative is positive:

```
3*3     = 9   = positive
-30*-30 = 900 = positive
```

Add them all up, but wait, then an array with many elements would have a larger error than a small array, so average them by the number of elements.

But we squared them all earlier, to force them positive.  Undo that damage with a square root.

That leaves you with a single number that represents, on average, the distance between every value of list1 to it's corresponding element value of list2.

If the RMSE value goes down over time we are happy because [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance) is decreasing.  "Shrinking the Variance" here is a primitive kind of machine learning algorithm.

### RMSE isn't the most accurate line fitting strategy, total least squares is:

Root mean squared error measures the vertical distance between the point and the line, so if your data is shaped like a banana, flat near the bottom and steep near the top, then the RMSE will report greater distances to points high, but short distances to points low when in fact the distances are equivalent. This causes a skew where the line prefers to be closer to points high than low.

If this is a problem the total least squares method fixes this:
https://mubaris.com/posts/linear-regression

### Gotchas that can break this RMSE function:

If there are nulls or infinity in either input list, then output rmse value is is going to not make sense.  There are three strategies to deal with nulls / missing values / infinities in either list: Ignore that component, zero it out or add a best guess or a uniform random noise to all timesteps.  Each remedy has its pros and cons depending on what your data means.  In general ignoring any component with a missing value is preferred, but this biases the RMSE toward zero making you think performance has improved when it really hasn't.  Adding random noise on a best guess could be preferred if there are lots of missing values.

In order to guarantee relative correctness of the RMSE output, you must eliminate all nulls/infinites from the input.

### RMSE has zero tolerance for outlier data points which don't belong

Root mean squared error squares relies on all data being right and all are counted as equal.  That means one stray point that's way out in left field is going to totally ruin the whole calculation.  To handle outlier data points and dismiss their tremendous influence after a certain threshold, see Robust estimators that build in a threshold for dismissal of outliers as extreme rare events that don't need their outlandish results to change our behavior.

Comment: Yeah, simple function. But if you need it in day-to-day use its nice to just have a correct solution available somewhere so that you don't have to reimplement it everytime ; )

Comment: @eric-leschinski, I would appreciate if you could have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45173451/scikit-learn-how-to-calculate-root-mean-square-error-rmse-in-percentage

Comment: @logicalx2 The difficulty of re implementing a 2 line function that can be compressed into 120 characters that always works as long as your programming language works, has to be juxtaposed against the childcare maintenance costs of 7 gigabyte sized black box libraries calling out to millions of lines of code, that stop working and break your flow and now you're mired rooting around the source to figure out why it's not producing correct root mean squared error values like it did before.  If you don't want to re-implement it, then keep the function in a central place and have everybody call it

Comment: One of best constructed answers I've seen on SO!

Comment: Nice analysis. I'd like to add that RMSE penalizes/weights large errors more than small errors.

Comment: I'm convinced that RMSE here, is one of the central operating principles of this universe and the human brain.  Meditating on this equation since the origin of this post back in 2016 and having forced it into every kind of activity where it belongs and doesn't belong, has produced gains.  RMSE is what your brain is doing in molecules inside your neurons, but shrouded in difficult-to-understand subatomic particle interactions.  The brain is a differential engine, this function is a differential engine of 1 dimension, and I'd bet 1 whole German mark that the universe is an implementation.

Answer (score 43):

In scikit-learn 0.22.0 you can pass `mean_squared_error()` the argument `squared=False` to return the RMSE.

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
mean_squared_error(y_actual, y_predicted, squared=False)
```

Comment: This is new feature and would be best if we use this.

Answer (score 28):

This is probably faster?:

```
n = len(predictions)
rmse = np.linalg.norm(predictions - targets) / np.sqrt(n)
```

Answer (score 19):

sklearn's `mean_squared_error` itself contains a parameter `squared` with default  value as `True` . If we set it to `False`, the same function will return RMSE instead of MSE.

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
rmse = mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred , squared=False)
```

Comment: The reference is here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error.html

Answer (score 11):

There is a library `ml_metrics` which is available without pre-installation in Kaggle's kernels, pretty lightweight and accessible through `pypi` (it can be installed easily and fast with `pip install ml_metrics`):

```py
from ml_metrics import rmse
rmse(actual=[0, 1, 2], predicted=[1, 10, 5])
# 5.507570547286102
```

It has few other interesting metrics which are not available in `sklearn`, like `mapk`.

References:

- https://pypi.org/project/ml_metrics/
- https://github.com/benhamner/Metrics/tree/master/Python

Answer (score 11):

Or by simply using only NumPy functions:

```
def rmse(y, y_pred):
    return np.sqrt(np.mean(np.square(y - y_pred)))
```

Where:

- y is my target
- y_pred is my prediction

Note that `rmse(y, y_pred)==rmse(y_pred, y)` due to the square function.

Answer (score 7):

Yes it is provided by SKLearn, we just need to mention `squared = False` in the arguments

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred, squared=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from sklearn import metrics              
import numpy as np
print(np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test,y_predict)))
```

Comment: Code only answers are more helpful if you add an explanation

Answer (score 1):

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
rmse = mean_squared_error(y_actual, y_predicted, squared=False)

or 

import math
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
rmse = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_actual, y_predicted))
```

Comment: May you provide some explanation to the code please?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Your answer duplicates already given high voted answers. It's advised to refrain from duplicating answers without adding something new and valuable.
And even in that cases some minor changes can be proposed to a given answer with a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example code that calculates the RMSE between two polygon file formats `PLY`. It uses both the `ml_metrics` lib and the `np.linalg.norm`:

```
import sys
import SimpleITK as sitk
from pyntcloud import PyntCloud as pc
import numpy as np
from ml_metrics import rmse

if len(sys.argv) < 3 or sys.argv[1] == "-h" or sys.argv[1] == "--help":
    print("Usage: compute-rmse.py <input1.ply> <input2.ply>")
    sys.exit(1)

def verify_rmse(a, b):
    n = len(a)
    return np.linalg.norm(np.array(b) - np.array(a)) / np.sqrt(n)

def compare(a, b):
    m = pc.from_file(a).points
    n = pc.from_file(b).points
    m = [ tuple(m.x), tuple(m.y), tuple(m.z) ]; m = m[0]
    n = [ tuple(n.x), tuple(n.y), tuple(n.z) ]; n = n[0]
    v1, v2 = verify_rmse(m, n), rmse(m,n)
    print(v1, v2)

compare(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

1. No, there is a ***library Scikit Learn for machine learning*** and it can be easily employed by using Python language. It has the a function for Mean Squared Error which i am sharing the link below:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error.html

2. The function is named mean_squared_error as given below, where y_true would be real class values for the data tuples and y_pred would be the predicted values, predicted by the machine learning algorithm you are using:

***mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred)***

3. You have to modify it to get RMSE (by using sqrt function using Python).This process is described in this link:
   https://www.codeastar.com/regression-model-rmsd/

**So, final code would be something like:**

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from math import sqrt

RMSD = sqrt(mean_squared_error(testing_y, prediction))

print(RMSD)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add absolute value `np.abs` if you are dealing with complex numbers.

```
import numpy as np
rms = np.sqrt(np.mean(np.abs(x-y)**2))
```

Note that if you use `np.linalg.norm` it already takes care of complex numbers.

```
import numpy as np
rms = np.linalg.norm(x-y)/np.sqrt(len(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Benchmark

For specific use case that you don't need overhead handler and always expecting numpy array input, the **fastest way is to manually write function in `numpy`**. Even more, you can use `numba` to speed it up if you call it frequently.

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import jit
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
```

```py
%%timeit
mean_squared_error(y[i],y[j], squared=False)
```

```
445 µs ± 90.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

```py
def euclidian_distance(y1, y2):
    """
    RMS Euclidean method
    """
    return np.sqrt(((y1-y2)**2).mean())
```

```py
%%timeit
euclidian_distance(y[i],y[j])
```

```
28.8 µs ± 2.54 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

```py
@jit(nopython=True)
def jit_euclidian_distance(y1, y2):
    """
    RMS Euclidean method
    """
    return np.sqrt(((y1-y2)**2).mean())
```

```py
%%timeit
jit_euclidian_distance(y[i],y[j])
```

```
2.1 µs ± 234 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

```py
@jit(nopython=True)
def jit2_euclidian_distance(y1, y2):
    """
    RMS Euclidean method
    """
    return np.linalg.norm(y1-y2)/np.sqrt(y1.shape[0])
```

```py
%%timeit
jit2_euclidian_distance(y[i],y[j])
```

```
2.67 µs ± 60.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Extra note: In my use case, `numba` give slightly different but negligible result on `np.sqrt(((y1-y2)**2).mean())`, where without `numba`, the result will be equal to `scipy` result. Try it yourself.