# How to calculate RMSE using IPython/NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I'm having issues trying to calculate root mean squared error in IPython using NumPy. I'm pretty sure the function is right, but when I try and input values, it gives me the following TypeError message:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'tuple'
```

Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np

def rmse(predictions, targets):
    return np.sqrt(((predictions - targets) ** 2).mean())

print rmse((2,2,3),(0,2,6))
```

Obviously something is wrong with my inputs. Do I need to establish the array before I put it in the `rmse():` line?

Comment: Here is better solutionss: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197492/root-mean-square-error-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Root mean square error in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197492/root-mean-square-error-in-python)

Answer (score 43):

In the rmse function, try:

```
return np.sqrt(np.mean((predictions-targets)**2))
```

Answer (score 7):

It says that subtraction is not defined for tuples.

Try

```
print rmse(np.array([2,2,3]), np.array([0,2,6]))
```

instead.

Answer (score 3):

From [Google formulas](https://g.co/kgs/pxDwej), RMSD or RSME is calculated from measured data and predicted or ground truth data for each measurement.

[image]

```latex
RMSD      = root-mean-square deviation (error)
i         = variable i
N         = number of non-missing data points
x_i       = actual observations time series
\hat{x}_i = estimated time series
```

And this is its numpy implementation using the fast norm function:

```py
rmse = np.linalg.norm(measured - truth) / np.sqrt(len(thruth))
```

`measured` and `truth` must have the same shape.

Comment: Sadly, if using `numba`, it is not the fastest. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71223074/11671779) for benchmark

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @miladiouss `np.linalg.norm(y1 - y2) / np.sqrt(len(y1))` is the fastest for pure numpy.

But, if you also use `numba`, that is not the fastest anymore. Benchmark using small time-series data (around 8 data points).

```py
import numba
import numpy as np

@jit(nopython=True)
def rmse(y1, y2):
    return np.sqrt(((y1-y2)**2).mean())
# 851 ns ± 1.05 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

@jit(nopython=True)
def rmse_norm(y1, y2):
    return np.linalg.norm(y1 - y2) / np.sqrt(len(y1))
# 1.17 µs ± 3.44 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```