Time-series correlating suspiciously high
I have two time series from 1986-01-01 to 2024-04-01 following CPI prices of meat and fish and I want to find the correlation between the both of them.
They are huge dataframes so below is a truncated version, but if you wanted to replicate this, the data is from this database
             Meat  Fish, seafood and other marine products
index                                                     
1986-01-01   65.1                                     60.6
1986-02-01   64.2                                     61.3
1986-03-01   64.2                                     61.3
1986-04-01   63.6                                     61.4
1986-05-01   64.0                                     61.9
1986-06-01   64.9                                     62.0
1986-07-01   66.5                                     62.2
1986-08-01   67.8                                     62.7
1986-09-01   71.3                                     63.1
1986-10-01   71.5                                     63.6
1986-11-01   72.1                                     65.3
1986-12-01   72.9                                     65.9
1987-01-01   72.8                                     67.1
1987-02-01   71.0                                     67.5
1987-03-01   70.5                                     67.6
1987-04-01   71.2                                     67.6
1987-05-01   72.0                                     67.8
1987-06-01   73.0                                     67.9
1987-07-01   73.4                                     68.4
1987-08-01   74.6                                     69.0
1987-09-01   73.8                                     69.3
1987-10-01   74.3                                     70.3
1987-11-01   73.8                                     70.3
...
2024-01-01  208.8                                    163.1
2024-02-01  206.2                                    162.5
2024-03-01  207.2                                    161.8
2024-04-01  207.6                                    161.9

Here is a graph as well:

As you can see, they follow similar trend but are by no means identical.
To correlate, I simply am doing this:
corr = df.corr(method='pearson')
print(corr)

And getting this output:




Meat
Fish, seafood and other marine products




Meat
1.000000
0.984597


Fish, seafood and other marine products
0.984597
1.000000



I've also tried scaling and logging, and get similar results.
Is it normal for these two dfs to be so highly correlated? Looking at the plot they are not identical, but a correlation of .98 is pretty well that. Could this be due to the size of the date range not catching the granularities of the data well enough and things becoming averaged?

"A correlation of .98 is pretty well that": you may be misunderstanding correlation. A correlation near 1 does not at all mean they're identical. The series [1, 2, 3, 4] and [2, 3, 4, 5] have a correlation of 1.

Comment above absolutely - There is no problem here. You seem to be looking for root mean square error instead.

... which at least scikit-learn has, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/33458959/12846804

There is nothing weird here, your two variables are highly correlated.
Think of the direct Meat vs Fish relationship, independently of the time:
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import linregress

slope, intercept, r, p, se = linregress(df['Meat'], df['Fish, seafood and other marine products'])
# (0.6615, 28.854, 0.9847, 0.0, 0.0055)

ax = df.plot.scatter(x='Meat', y='Fish, seafood and other marine products')
xs = np.linspace(*ax.get_xlim())

ax.plot(xs, xs*slope+intercept, color='k', ls=':')

Output:

Now you can see that despite the high correlation, a linear model is not ideal here. If you compute the Spearman's correlation, it is even greater:
from scipy.stats import pearsonr, spearmanr

pearsonr(df['Meat'], df['Fish, seafood and other marine products'])
# PearsonRResult(statistic=0.9847221299614347, pvalue=0.0)

spearmanr(df['Meat'], df['Fish, seafood and other marine products'])
# SignificanceResult(statistic=0.9875824349732326, pvalue=0.0)

