# Python Pandas: Simple example of calculating RMSE from data frame

Tags: python, pandas

Need a simple example of calculating RMSE with Pandas DataFrame. Providing there is function that returns in cycle true and predicted value:

```
def fun (data):
   ...
   return trueVal, predVal

for data in set:
   fun(data)
```

And then some code puts these results in the following data frame where `x` is a real value and `p` is a predicted value:

```
In [20]: d
Out[20]: {'p': [1, 10, 4, 5, 5], 'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}

In [21]: df = pd.DataFrame(d)

In [22]: df
Out[22]: 
    p  x
0   1  1
1  10  2
2   4  3
3   5  4
4   5  5
```

Questions:

1) How to put results from `fun` function in `df` data frame?

2) How to calculate RMSE using `df` data frame?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197492/root-mean-square-error-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Root mean square error in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197492/root-mean-square-error-in-python)

Answer (score 28):

***Question 1***
This depends on the format that data is in.  And I'd expect you already have your true values, so this function is just a pass through.

***Question 2***

With `pandas`
`((df.p - df.x) ** 2).mean() ** .5`

With `numpy`
`(np.diff(df.values) ** 2).mean() ** .5`

Comment: shouldn't it be `((df.p - df.x) ** 2).mean() ** .5` for pandas, as it's root **mean** squared error?

Comment: Username doesn't check out :)

Answer (score 2):

**Question 1**

I understand you already have a dataframe df. To add the new values in new rows do the following:

```
for data in set:

    trueVal, predVal = fun(data)

    auxDf = pd.DataFrame([[predVal, trueVal]], columns = ['p', 'x'])

    df.append(auxDf, ignore_index = True)
```

**Question 2**

To calculate RMSE using df, I recommend you to use the scikit learn function.

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error 
realVals = df.x
predictedVals = df.p
mse = mean_squared_error(realVals, predictedVals)
# If you want the root mean squared error
# rmse = mean_squared_error(realVals, predictedVals, squared = False)
```

It's very important that you don't have null values in the columns, otherwise it won't work