# Reading in Netcdf file and calculating RMSE in Python

Tags: python, statistics, netcdf

I have a netcdf file. I have two variables in this file: wspd_wrf_m and wspd_sodar_o. I want to read in the netcdf file and calculate the RMSE value between wspd_wrf_m and wspd_sodar_o.

The variables are with the dimensions (Days, times) which is (1094, 24)
I want to calculate the RMSE from the last 365 days of the files. Can you help me with this?

I know I need to use:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np

g = Dataset('station_test_new.nc','r',format='NETCDF3_64BIT')
wspd_wrf = g.variables["wspd_wrf_m"][:,:]
wspd_sodar = g.variables["wspd_sodar_o"][:,:]
```

But how do I select the last 365 days of hourly data that I need and calculate RMSE from this?

Answer (score 1):

Selecting the last 365 days is a matter of slicing the arrays to the correct size. For example:

```
import numpy as np
var = np.zeros((1094, 24))
print(var.shape, var[729:,:].shape, var[-365:,:].shape)
```

which prints:

> (1094, 24) (365, 24) (365, 24)

So both `var[729:,:]` and `var[-365:,:]` slice the last 365 days (with all hourly values) out of your 1094 day sized array.

There is more information / are more examples in the [Numpy manual](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html).

There are plenty of examples of how to calculate the RMSE in Python (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197492/root-mean-square-error-in-python) one). Please give that a try, and if you can't get it to work, update your question with your attempts.